# What pilot safety features and equipment are on an A380?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, airbus-a380

What safety features and equipment protect the *pilots* (not, protect the *plane*) in the cockpit on a Airbus A380?
For example I know they have life jackets: but I wonder what else?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Aviation.SE. To me it is unclear what you are after. Are after features of the pilots or features of the cockpit? Either way, the question is likely tooo broad.

Comment: Entire books can (and indeed, have) been written on this subject. Everything in a cockpit is a safety feature, depending on your definition. You should narrow down your question significantly.

Comment: 1) The controls 2) The instruments 3) Maps manuals and handbooks, 4) Each other. Now if you want a more detailed answer, you are going to have to ask something more precise :)

Comment: The two pilots, because if they don't safely use the features it isn't very safe is it?

Comment: Please answer my question!!

Comment: This question is still very broad.  I would suggest adding the scenario you're thinking of or the category of safety feature you're referring to.  To give an example of why this is broad, consider the safety features in a modern car:  mirrors, seatbelts, airbags, cruise control disengage, emergency brake, horn, headrest, collapsible steering column, blind spot indicators, radio dimmer switch, etc.  Explaining all the safety features in a car would take several pages, and cockpits are several times more complex.  Please define the category or usage scenario you're thinking of.

Comment: Rewrite your question to tell if you mean things that add safety to passengers, or the crew, or to everyone. Tell us what kind of safety you are looking for: safety for persons (like oxygen mask), safety to prevent collision, safety to fly at night, safety in case of accident, on the sea, on the ground... etc. Safety belts are present in the cockpit, you probably don't want to know that, so explain please (by editing your question).

Comment: @mins I think the OP is looking for seat belt, oxygen mask; and possibly fire extinguisher, locked door, first aid kit, emergency exits, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *Saftey guy* asks about features like the escape hatch from the [747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25896/what-is-this-hatch-above-the-cockpit-of-a-747%20747). Probably there is something similiar on the A380:
[image: A380-800 Cockpit Lufthansa]

I think that I can read the label **Escape Rope** on the cover of at the top right. You can look around inside the cockpit [here](http://magazin.lufthansa.com/de/de/flotte/airbus-a380-800/panoramafoto-blick-ins-cockpit-a380-800/).

Comment: According to https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A380_Briefing_For_Pilots_Part%202.pdf the hatch in your picture leads to the main avionics bay. Said bay is also apparently accessible from outside the aircraft and from the forward cargo hold. The document in question doesn't make it clear if those accesses can be opened from inside the bay or not.